# bcrypt-ruby 3.1.2 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension in OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I encounter this issue with ruby version 2.1.10, OSX El Capitan and the description of error as below:

Installing bcrypt-ruby 3.1.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
checking for ruby/util.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
compiling crypt.c
compiling crypt_blowfish.c
compiling crypt_gensalt.c
compiling wrapper.c
linking shared-object bcrypt_ext.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-   L/Users/travis/.sm/pkg/active/lib'

make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/local/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory
make: *** [.RUBYARCHDIR.time] Error 1

make install failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When upgrading to Ruby 2.1.x in OS X El Capitan: 
For some of the native extensions to build you need to make sure that the coreutils package is installed.

To do this run:

`brew install coreutils`

This could also cause similar failures for raindrops, pg, kgio, http_parser, fast-stemmer, unf_ext, ffi, debug-inspector, and nokogiri